# Set individual timeouts in VertX per request

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x

Is it possible to set individual timeouts per request in VertX?

Doing this,

```
val vertx = Vertx.vertx(VertxOptions().setMaxWorkerExecuteTime(15000))
```

sets the timeout for all requests.
Certain things like huge reports needs a bit more than the default 30 seconds.

This is what I'm currently doing (simplified):

```
val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
val router = Router.router(vertx)

router.route(url).handler { rtx ->
    rtx.request().bodyHandler { btx ->
        rtx.vertx().executeBlocking<RestResponse>({ block ->

            val timer = timer(period = 150000) {
                block.fail("timeout")
            }

            ... blocking code here ...

            timer.cancel()
            block.complete(res)

        }, { block ->


        }
    }
}
```

Is there an official way to this in VertX or should the above be fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vert.x Web `Route` has a `blockingHandler` method which you can combine with a `TimeoutHandler` (returns `503` if a request times out before the response is written).

```
router.get("/foo").handler(TimeoutHandler.create(150000))
router.get("/foo").blockingHandler({ routingContext ->
  // Blocking code
})
```

Also, `VertxOptions.setMaxWorkerExecuteTime` just tells Vert.x when the blocked (worker) thread warning should be displayed. The value is expected in **nanoseconds**.